# Java get user details

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have to write a program to get user details which appear like this:

```
Author’s Details
****************
Name: J. Beans

YOB: 1969

Age: 41

Book Details

************

       Title: *Wonderful Java*
       ISBN: *978 0 470 10554 9*
       Publisher: *Wiley*
```

This is what I've done but it does not work, can anyone help me to find out the problem ?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
public class UserDetails
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    input sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
    System.out.print("Please enter author's surname:");
    sname = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please the initial of author's first name:");
    fname = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the year the author was born:");
    born = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the author's book title:");
    title = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the book's ISBN:");
    isbn = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Please enter the publisher of the book:");
    publisher = input.nextLine;

    System.out.println("Author's detail");
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("Name:" + fname + sname);
    System.out.println("YOB:" + born);
    System.out.println("Age" + born);
    System.out.println("Book Details");
    System.out.println("**********************");
    System.out.println("Title:" + "*" + title + "*");
    System.out.println("ISBN:" + "*" + isbn + "*");
    System.out.println("Publisher:" + "*" + publisher + "*");
  }
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Please don't say compile error (the line with the variable definitions looks weird, maybe a typo).

Comment: Do you use something like Eclipse? It shows you a lot of errors in the syntax already.

Comment: You have every right to ask questions like this, but for a better understanding I *really* recommend following some tutorials on Java and/or read a beginners book. They should not only tell you *how* but more importantly *why*.

Answer (score 2):

Among other things, change this:

```
  System scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  input sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
```

to this:

```
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
```

---

See also:

#### Java language:

- [How to declare variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

#### API:

- [`java.lang.String`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)
- [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

If you are really serious about learning how to program, follow everyone's recommendation and:

- Read books.
- Study [tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/getStarted/index.html).
- Use an IDE (Eclipse is a good one, and it's [free to download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/))
- Practice a lot.
- Ask questions a lot.

Comment: Would be nice if you told him WHY he should change it this way.

Comment: @Helper Not really, that's basic java syntax. Follow a java tutorial and it'll work out. That said, the compiler is quite clear in why it doesn't work. Good advice is, if you are starting like this don't make an entire program but add line for line and compile in between.

Answer (score 2):

hi you just wrongly use  classes.Your code shoul be

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserDetails {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
        System.out.print("Please enter author's surname:");

        sname = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please the initial of author's first name:");
        fname = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the year the author was born:");
        born = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the author's book title:");
        title = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the book's ISBN:");
        isbn = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter the publisher of the book:");
        publisher = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Author's detail");
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("Name:" + fname + sname);
        System.out.println("YOB:" + born);
        System.out.println("Age" + born);
        System.out.println("Book Details");
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("Title:" + "*" + title + "*");
        System.out.println("ISBN:" + "*" + isbn + "*");
        System.out.println("Publisher:" + "*" + publisher + "*");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nit-picky, but he should also look at the way he is outputting the Strings. For example he is going to output "Name:JohnDoe" instead of "Name: John Doe" because he isn't concatenating a space into the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of syntax and semantic errors. This works:

```
 import java.util.Scanner ;
  public class UserDetails {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  String sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
  System.out.print("Please enter author's surname:");
  sname = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please the initial of author's first name:");
  fname = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter the year the author was born:");
  born = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter the author's book title:");
  title = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter the book's ISBN:");
  isbn = scan.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Please enter the publisher of the book:");
  publisher = scan.nextLine();

  System.out.println("Author's detail");
  System.out.println("**********************");
  System.out.println("Name:" + fname + sname);
  System.out.println("YOB:" + born);
  System.out.println("Age" + born);
  System.out.println("Book Details");
  System.out.println("**********************");
  System.out.println("Title:" + "*" + title + "*");
  System.out.println("ISBN:" + "*" + isbn + "*");
  System.out.println("Publisher:" + "*" + publisher + "*");
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but you have a couple errors and a typo.

System scan = new Scanner(System.in);
This should be:
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
What you are doing here is creating a new object reference of type scanner named scan -- not System.

Next problem:
 input sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;
This is again, a declaration issue with types. Each of these variables is a string reference -- should declare this as;
 String sname, fname, born, title, isbn, publisher;

Lastly, you have a typo:
 publisher = input.nextLine;
You forgot the () that indicate this is a function call. Should be: 
 publisher = input.nextLine();

There may be some other more subtle issues, but this should get your code to compile and run at least :).